# How to get the start times and end times for each status

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to list **start time** and **end times** when the door was **OPEN** with this sample data

Here are some sample data from the table

```
currenttime,       door_status, 
12-10-15 12:02:00    Open
12-10-15 12:01:00    Open
12-10-15 12:00:30    Open
12-10-15 11:59:30    Open
12-10-15 11:59:00    Open
12-10-15 11:58:30    Open
12-10-15 11:58:00    Closed
12-10-15 11:57:30    Closed
12-10-15 11:57:00    Open
12-10-15 11:56:00    Open
12-10-15 11:55:30    Open
12-10-15 11:55:00    Open
```

Here is the expected result

```
start_Time             end_Time               time_it_was_open

12-10-15 11:58:30      12-10-15 12:02:00       3 mins 30 secs
12-10-15 11:55:00      12-10-15 11:57:00       2 mins
```

**Tried Queries**

**query 1:**

```
SELECT current_time_open, current_time_closed, door1  FROM(
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN door1 = 'Open' THEN currenttime
    END AS current_time_open,
   CASE
        WHEN door1 = 'Closed' THEN currenttime
    END AS current_time_closed,
   door1
FROM
    (SELECT 
        r1.currenttime, r1.temp, r1.door1
    FROM
        rcs_data r1 ) as g1 GROUP BY currenttime DESC) as t1;
```

**query 2:**

```
SELECT MAX(current_time_open), MAX(current_time_closed), TIMEDIFF(MAX(current_time_open),MAX(current_time_closed)) FROM (SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN door1 = 'Open' THEN currenttime
    END AS current_time_open,
   CASE
        WHEN door1 = 'Closed' THEN currenttime
    END AS current_time_closed
FROM
    (SELECT 
        currenttime, temp, door1
    FROM
        rcs_data) as g1 GROUP BY currenttime DESC) as t1;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your questions and add your attempted query.

Comment: Please add a "Expected Result" block as it help us to use your dummy data to become what you expect.

Comment: I have added it now. @MarcoAurélioDeleu

Comment: @BrokenBinary, I have added the queries tried

Comment: @SamuelThampy consider accepting an answer as correct if you don't need further assistance so other people don't bother to try different approaches.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu, ok, but how to accept as an answer correct, I have no reputation to even increase it.

Comment: There's a tick button below the down vote. Click on it to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

here is one variant to do this:

```
select *, unix_timestamp(endtime)-unix_timestamp(starttime) as dur_seconds
from (
select min(currenttime) as starttime, max(currenttime) as endtime
from (
select currenttime, coalesce(
 (select min(currenttime) from t as b where b.currenttime > a.currenttime and b.door_status != a.door_status),
 (select max(currenttime) from t as b where b.currenttime > a.currenttime and b.door_status = a.door_status),
 a.currenttime) as mxt
from t as a
where a.door_status = 'Open'
) as q
group by mxt
) as q2
```

so, the main idea is to "assign" some unique ID to the groups of "open" statuses, in this particular case its either first time of closed status or last time of open status, or current time for the last "open" status in table